# Как решить проблему у UIKit и Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gems, uikit

Есть RoR проект. Изначально использовал в нем Bootstrap 4, но пришлось отказаться от него. Он слишком сырой, да и UIKit наиболее подходит для этого проекта.

Проблема вот в чем. Если переходить по разделам внутри одного контроллера, то примерно 70% компонентов UIKit крашатся. Например, компонент Toggle просто-напросто не переключает. приходится обновлять страницу. Если говорить о странице index с пагинатором, то при переходе на следующую страницу все блоки внутри компонента Dynamic Grid сливаются и выходит какая-то куча. Опять же, помогает перезапуск страницы.

Пробовал сделать так:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(event) {
    var grid = UIkit.grid(element, { /* options */ });
});
```

Но это не решило проблему. Все тоже самое, как и при простом:

```
<div data-uk-grid>
```

Пока вижу единственный вариант - это отключать в ссылках Turbolinks. Но тогда возникает надобность в геме в целом.

Никогда не сталкивался с подобными проблемами в Bootstrap 3 и 4 версий.

Как поступить? Кто с этим сталкивался? Почему возникает проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вы используете ROR 5 с новым turbolinks, в котором изменились события. Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
  //...
});
```